# ASP.net RequiredFieldValidator VisualStudio 2012

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a project with ASP.net c#.
I want RequiredFieldValidator to check my textbox. I am adding validator, and it works perfectly fine in Visual Studio 2010. But once i did the same thing, exactly same thing, it does not work in Visual Studio 2012. I am recieving this error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.EnsureJqueryRegistered() +2171326
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.RegisterUnobtrusiveScript() +10
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +9576177
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

My regards...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735928/in-asp-net-web-application-visual-basic-the-requiredfieldvalidator-doest-work.)

It looks like you have to either remove this line:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
</appSettings>
```

Or change it to this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
</appSettings>
```

Which will disable it for you.

Alternatively you could add something like this to your Global.asax

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition {
     Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
     DebugPath = "~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js",
     CdnPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
     CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js"
});
```

Hopefully this gets you squared away!

Answer (score 4):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode =System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
}
```

Just copy & paste in C# Code

Answer (score -2):

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
</appSettings>
```

never use jquery script 
it will go to server end every time which give bad effect to your application perfomance
just add  tag(mention above) in web config

within configuration tag

Comment: This is the same as saying "never eat cake, it'll make you fat"